# How to prevent html elements from being in top of each other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, responsive

I have a problem I couldn't solve.
I have two html elements that I don't want to be in top of each other like the pictrue.[image: Problem image]

What I want to do is to seperate them away from each other so user can see them

The banner css code:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

The product css code:

```
.product-grid {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 72px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

I tried everything it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try change
Product grid position to absolute

Comment: It's making it worse LOL

Comment: in that case i need to see your html